# Left Joins on several tables where any one of them can be master

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I have simplified my actual live code since I don't want to overflow this post with irrelevant data.

I have (sadly) seven tables, one for each weekday, that contains exactly the same information except for two items and that is the newspaper title and the amount of newspapers the customer should receive. Now any customer can have any number of newspapers (from a single title and all the way up to 20 different titles) and they can have any number of newspapers of that title each day (0 to massive amounts) - BUT! and here comes the kicker - they can have the amount of 0 on any given day.
What I need in the end is this:

```
Customer1, New York Times, 0, 7, 3, 2, 2, 10, 10
```

Which would indicate that Customer1 wants 7 New York Tiems on Tuesday (yes, I'm from Sweden, the week DOES start with monday), 10 on saturday and 10 on sunday e.tc.
Now my 7 different tables I have now will not contain any info at all if the customer doesn't have any papers on that given day which means that I cannot do this:

```
    select t1.name, t1.title, t1.amount, t2.amount,
           t3.amount, t4.amount, t5.amount, t6.amount,
           t7.amount
    from table_mon t1
    left join table_tue t2 on t2.name = t1.name
    left join table_wen t3 on t3.name = t1.name
    left join table_thu t4 on t4.name = t1.name
    left join table_fri t5 on t5.name = t1.name
    left join table_sat t6 on t6.name = t1.name
    left join table_sun t7 on t7.name = t1.name
```

since monday might be the day that this particular customer dosn't have any paper and thus is not part of the monday table at all. Theoretically he can be in only one of the tables and I have no idea which one.

How can I write a join where I don't know which is the "master" table??

Comment: This seems like a bad database design. is it too late to change?

Comment: Shouldn't the join also include the title column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to know which is the `master` table you can use UNION ALL to do this combine all into one single result or derived table.

```
SELECT name, title, SUM(MON), SUM(TUE), SUM(WED), SUM(THU)
FROM
(
  SELECT name, title, amount as MON, NULL as TUE, NULL as WED, NULL as THU, . . .
  FROM   table_mon
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name, title, NULL as MON, amount as TUE, NULL as WED, NULL as THU, . . .
  FROM   table_tue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT name, title, NULL as MON, NULL as TUE, amount as WED, NULL as THU, . . .
  FROM   table_wed
) d
GROUP BY name, title
```

Comment: Sadly I get this result then: `Customer1, New York Times, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` and second row `Customer1, New York Times, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` and so on...

Comment: AHA! I had a date component in my live tables also which messed it up for me. I will not take that with me and it'll be alright.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, title, 
       sum(a1) mon, sum(a2) tue, sum(a3) wed, sum(a4) thu, sum(a5) fri,
       sum(a6) sat, sum(a7) sun from (
  select name,title,amount a1,0 a2,0 a3,0 a4,0 a5,0 a6,0 a7 FROM table_mon union all
  select name,title,0,amount,0,0,0,0,0 FROM table_tue union all
  select name,title,0,0,amount,0,0,0,0 FROM table_wed union all
  select name,title,0,0,0,amount,0,0,0 FROM table_thu union all
  select name,title,0,0,0,0,amount,0,0 FROM table_fri union all
  select name,title,0,0,0,0,0,amount,0 FROM table_sat union all
  select name,title,0,0,0,0,0,0,amount FROM table_sun 
) week
group by name,title
```

Yeah, squirrel has beaten me to it. I was just too slow. Should not have attempted editing my answer on a weak android phone for ten minutes ;-).

But, as freakyhat said already, and as you can see from the derived table in my solution, it would be a good idea to store all the values in *one* table ...

Comment: I had some troubles with this solution but it's cause I had a DATE column in my live tables, so removing that made it work! (See comments on Squirrels note below)